# Pandas dataframe: Check if data is monotonically decreasing

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
    Balance       Jan       Feb       Mar       Apr
0  9.724135  0.389376  0.464451  0.229964  0.691504
1  1.114782  0.838406  0.679096  0.185135  0.143883
2  7.613946  0.960876  0.220274  0.788265  0.606402
3  0.144517  0.800086  0.287874  0.223539  0.206002
4  1.332838  0.430812  0.939402  0.045262  0.388466
```

I would like to group the rows by figuring out if the values from Jan through to Apr are monotonically decreasing (as in rows indexed 1 and 3) or not, and then add up the balances for each group, i.e. in the end I would like to end up with two numbers (1.259299 for the decreasing time series, and 18.670919 for the others).

I think if I could add a column "is decreasing" containg booleans I could do the sums using pandas' groupby, but how would I create this column?

Thanks,
Anne

Comment: Were you thinking about a column of booleans for each month?  You have the switch from decreasing to increasing happening at different rows.

Comment: Ahh nevermind.  You mean decreasing month to month.  Across the columns.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use one of the `is_monotonic` functions from algos:

```
In [10]: months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr']

In [11]: df.loc[:, months].apply(lambda x: pd.algos.is_monotonic_float64(-x)[0],
                                       axis=1)
Out[11]:
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

The `is_monotonic` checks whether an array it's *decreasing* hence the `-x.values`.

(This seems substantially faster than Tom's solution, even using the small DataFrame provided.)

Comment: @TomAugspurger I think the word you are looking for is "pandastic"... \*ahem\*.

Comment: Thanks Andy, this works beautifully. I have a bit of a stupid question - I have been trying to find documentation on the is_monotonic function and I can't seem to find any online. Do you happen to have a link?

Comment: Another question - can't I just write `-x` instead of `-x.values` in `df.loc[:, months].apply(lambda x: pd.algos.is_monotonic_float64(-x.values)[0],axis=1)`? I tried it and it *seemed* to work.

Comment: @Anne apparently so! :)

Comment: @Anne - Newer version of pandas removed the `pd.algos` module from the public API. `is_monotonic` is now available as a Series attribute (see my answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48300653/8425408)).

Answer (score 7):

```
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr']
```

Transpose so that we can use the `diff` method (which doesn't take an axis argument).
We fill in the first row (January) with 0.  Otherwise it's `NaN`.

```
In [77]: df[months].T.diff().fillna(0) <= 0
Out[77]: 
         0     1      2     3      4
Jan   True  True   True  True   True
Feb  False  True   True  True  False
Mar   True  True  False  True   True
Apr  False  True   True  True  False
```

To check if it's monotonically decreasing, use the .all() method.  By default this goes over axis 0, the rows (months).

```
In [78]: is_decreasing = (df[months].T.diff().fillna(0) <= 0).all()

In [79]: is_decreasing
Out[79]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool

In [80]: df['is_decreasing'] = is_decreasing

In [81]: df
Out[81]: 
    Balance       Jan       Feb       Mar       Apr is_decreasing
0  9.724135  0.389376  0.464451  0.229964  0.691504         False
1  1.114782  0.838406  0.679096  0.185135  0.143883          True
2  7.613946  0.960876  0.220274  0.788265  0.606402         False
3  0.144517  0.800086  0.287874  0.223539  0.206002          True
4  1.332838  0.430812  0.939402  0.045262  0.388466         False
```

And like you suggested, we can groupby `is_decreasing` and sum:

```
In [83]: df.groupby('is_decreasing')['Balance'].sum()
Out[83]: 
is_decreasing
False            18.670919
True              1.259299
Name: Balance, dtype: float64
```

It's times like these when I love pandas.

Answer (score 2):

**Pandas 0.19** added a [`Series.is_monotonic`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.is_monotonic.html) attribute (as mentioned, the `algos` module was removed from Pandas public API).

As @Liam notes in his answer, `is_monotonic` is in fact an alias for `is_monotonic_increasing`, so for clarity I'd recommended directly using either `is_monotonic_increasing` or `is_monotonic_decreasing`.

Anyway, both are non-strict (i.e. `is_monotonic_decreasing` returns `True` when the sequence is either decreasing **or** equal), but you can combine them with [`is_unqiue`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.is_unique.html) if you need strictness.

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[1,1,1],'C':[3,2,1]})
my_df

Out[32]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  1  3
1  2  1  2
2  3  1  1

my_df.apply(lambda x: x.is_monotonic_increasing)  # row-wise monotonic (default axis is 0)

Out[33]: 
A     True
B     True
C    False
dtype: bool

my_df.apply(lambda x: x.is_monotonic_increasing, axis=1)  # column-wise monotonic

Out[34]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: The question was for row-wise, not series/columns. For this to work (i.e. check if A<B<C) you would need to transpose or see my answer below

Comment: Thanks @Liam, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: What if one needs to do this within a group? e.g., `my_df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.is_monotonic_increasing)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr']

df[df.loc[:, months].apply(lambda x: x.is_monotonic,axis=1)]
```

Note: pandas states that `is_monotonic_increasing` is an alias for `is_monotonic` so you can use either one