# Pandas algos package: where to find documentation OR more info on "is_monotonic_float64"

Tags: python, pandas

someone pointed me to a function in pandas.algos a couple of days ago (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17705498/2565842) and I can't find any documentation on this. When I type "algos" or "is_monotonic_float64" (the function in question) in the pandas search box on http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/, I don't get any results. Similarly, when I ask Google I don't get anything useful either.

The reason why I am looking for the docs is that I am having trouble with the types the function accepts. I have written two functions like this:

```
def is_monotonic(time_series, cols):
    return time_series.loc[:,cols].apply(lambda x: 
           pandas.algos.is_monotonic_float64(x)[0] if is_type(x, float) else "non_numeric data", 
           axis=1)

def is_type(series, t):
    return series.apply(lambda x: type(x) == t).all()
```

I run this on the following dataframe

```
           0          1          2          3          4
A          t          t          t          t          t
B  0.2583974  0.3311106   0.933452        NaN  0.1908287
C  0.4400121  0.9548238  0.2953693  0.7027355  0.6149148
D  0.4049013  0.5930965  0.7073495  0.3801416  0.4931772
```

but then get as error

```
ValueError: ("Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'float64_t' but got Python object"
```

When I check the types in the dataframe, the first row is strings, the others of type 'float'. Do I need to do some sort of type conversion to numpy.float64 here?

Comment: these are not public functions and are used (currently only on indexes); that said these could be used (in your pointed to example) on data as well, just not implemented; why don't you open an issue to request ``is_monotonic`` on columns (pretty easy to do), what are you trying to do?

Comment: you can figure this out btw, by sorting by a column (or columns), then calling ``is_monotonic`` on the index

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. This might be a silly question, but how/where/who with would I issue a request?

Comment: not silly at all! http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/ click on issues....also many goodies in the docs...so checkout the cookbook and 10min to pandas

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the algos documentation. If something is undocumented you can always, [find it in the source code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/src/generated.pyx). This function is written is Cython for high performance, so it's a particularly dense example.

But about that `ValueError`, as you might expect, each column's datatype has to be general enough to accomodate all of its data. Override that by executing `df.convert_objects(convert_numeric)`. Anything that is not a number (e.g., `t`) will be replaced with `NaN`. All numbers should become `float64` type, and I would then expect `is_monotonic_float64` for work.

Alternatively, I see there is also a `pd.algos.is_monotonic_object`, but I'm not sure how it behaves, e.g. how it compares `t` to `0.25823974`.